# JavaFx：How to make 'comic sans ms' font to be italic?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In my javafx program,I can't make my text that uses 'comic sans ms' font to be italic.Dose javafx not suppose 'comic sans ms' to be italic?
How can I make this font to be italic? 
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to "Windows/Fonts" folder.
2. Find "Comic Sans MS". Click on it. You should see four different types of Comic Sans, which are "Italic", "Bold", "Bold Italic", and "Regular".
3. Copy the italic Comic Sans (probably named as "comici.ttf") font type and paste it to the "src" folder under your project.
4. Refresh and rebuild your project.
5. Set the font of your Text using the following code line:

   ```
   text.setFont(Font.loadFont(getClass().getResource("comici.ttf").toExternalForm(), 32));
   ```